# Test fails with Winston logger implemention in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, winston, jasmine2.0

**Background:** I'm using Jasmine2 as my test framework for Protractor and trying to implement a logger mechanism in the framework using winston package for better logging.

**Problem:** Test fails with below Non-Zero error in cmd which was working fine before including winston in the script. Could you please help me in implementing it correct.

**Non-Zero Error:**

```
Report destination:   target\e2e\screenshots\my-report.html
[20:28:52] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:28:52] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub

[20:28:56] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:28:56] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[20:28:56] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[20:28:56] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Below are the corresponding files for reference:

**Scenario_01.js:**

```
describe('Scenario_01', function() {

 var Logging = require('./scripts/LoggingMech.js');
 var common = require('./scripts/CloseBrowsers.js');    
 var Login = require('./scripts/Login.js'); 


 it('Login', function() {
         browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); 
         Login.login('admin','Adminpwd')
          .catch(error => Logging.Logger.log(error));
     });

afterAll(function(){
    common.closeBrowsers();
});
});
```

**Login.js:**

```
var Login = function() {

     this.login = async function(username, passwordKey){
     await browser.get('http://testwebsite.com/showCust');
     await element(by.name('USER')).sendKeys(username);
     await element(by.name('PASSWORD')).sendKeys(passwordKey);
     await element(by.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/input[9]')).click();
     await element(by.name('YES')).click();
     //browser.sleep(10000);

};
}
module.exports = new Login();
```

**LoggingMech.js**

```
const winston = require('winston');
var Logging = function() {

     this.Logger = function(){
      const logger = winston.createLogger({

           level: 'info',
           format: format.simple(),
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.Console(),
                new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'TodaysLog.log' })
                        ]
});

};
}
module.exports = new Logging();
```

Comment: Can someone help me with above issue pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`const logger = winston.createLogger...`You are creating a winston reference but it's never passed anywhere. You are just storing it in a constant. You would have to make it a property of `Logger` attribute and then create a new instance of `Logging.Logger` and call `log()` on it.

#### Fix

> You would have to make it a property of Logger attribute.

In `LoggingMech.js` you do `this.logger = winston.createLogger` instead of `const logger = winston.createLogger`

> and then create a new instance of Logging.Logger and call log() on it.

```
var Logging = require('./scripts/LoggingMech.js');
// logs foo
(new Logging.Logger()).log('foo');
```

But I think you are doing it more complex as it is needed. For implementing the logger you could simply change your `LoggingMech.js` file to the following:

```
const winston = require('winston');
module.exports = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: format.simple(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'TodaysLog.log'
        })
    ]
});
```

And call it like:

```
var Logging = require('./scripts/LoggingMech.js');
Logging.log('foo');
```

The configuration of the logger still is encapsulated within `LoggingMech.js` and it's way simpler to call. The code is also easier to maintain.

## Update 1: Logging with winston

The `winston.log()` method accepts only a log object and not a string.

```
// logs "I am a log message."
winston.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: 'I am a log message.'
}
```

For logging plain strings you can use `logger.info()`.

## Update 2: Full winston logging example

A working log example. Following code works for me on my machinde:

#### winston.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
module.exports = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'TodaysLog.log'
        })
    ]
});
```

#### index.js

```
var Logging = require('./winston');
var message = {
    level: 'info',
    message: 'Hello distributed log files!'
  };

  Logging.log(message);
  Logging.info('sdf');
  Logging.error(message);
  Logging.warn(message);
```

#### logged content in TodaysLog.log

```
{"level":"info","message":"Hello distributed log files!"}
{"message":"sdf","level":"info"}
{"level":"error","message":"Hello distributed log files!"}
{"level":"warn","message":"Hello distributed log files!"}
```

Comment: @sylvanBregy: Thanks for your valuable time and solution pal. With above mentioned and some minor changes, I could able to see the logfile being created now. But, still unable to write anything in the same with "Logging.log("foo");" added in "Login.js" file. Ends up error: "[17:12:51] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1". Could you help me with this issue as well please ?

Comment: I would basically like to log everything that happens in the automation process. How can I log it all from Scenario_01.js ? Could you help me with this issue as well please ?

Comment: I had a quick look into winston module. It appears that you have to log in a different way. I updated my answer.

Comment: @sylvanBregy: Test passed, but with nothing written in the Log File. Not sure if I understood the correct way. Could pls check the below answer (due to space constraint here in comments section) with the changes made in corresponding files as it would be of huge help.

Answer (score 0):

@sylvanBregy: Below are the files with recommended changes for reference.

I could witness the test to be complete with successful login , but not sure why there was an error triggered in console.

Also, nothing was written in the logFile as well :(

**Scenario_01**

```
describe('Scenario_01', function() {
console.log("Into Scenario1");

 var Logging = require('./scripts/LoggingMech.js');
 var common = require('./scripts/CloseBrowsers.js');    
 var Login = require('./scripts/Login.js'); 


 it('Login', function() {
         browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); 
         Login.login('admin','Adminpwd')
           Logging.info("foo"); //Neither this worked nor the below
           Logging.info();
     });

afterAll(function(){
    common.closeBrowsers();
});
});
```

**Login.js**

```
var Login = function() {
  console.log("Into Login Function");

     this.login = async function(username, passwordKey){
     await browser.get('http://testwebsite.com/showCust');
     await element(by.name('USER')).sendKeys(username);
     await element(by.name('PASSWORD')).sendKeys(passwordKey);
     await element(by.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/input[9]')).click();
     await element(by.name('YES')).click();
     //browser.sleep(10000);

};
}
module.exports = new Login();
```

**LoggingMech.js**

```
const winston = require('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\winston\\lib\\winston');
//const winston = require('winston');

module.exports = winston.createLogger({
                     level: 'info',
                     format: 'simple',
                     transports: [
                            new winston.transports.Console(),
                            new winston.transports.File({filename:'./logs/TodaysLog.log',level: 'info'})
                            ],
});
```

**Console Log**

```
Report destination:   target\e2e\screenshots\my-report.html
[20:22:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[20:22:58] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
Into Scenario1
Into Login Function

[20:23:03] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[20:23:03] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[20:23:03] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[20:23:03] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: I would really like to help you here. But before we go on, you should take a moment and focus on fixing the error message displaying. Usually when tests are failing, you should haev some sort of exact error message. An error code -1 or 1 is not really helpful though. 

For resolving this issue, I recommend reproducing the whole thing in a multiuser editor. I would like to work on the live example with you together If you are willing to set it up here:  https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Can you please try to add an `expect` block in your tests? I think with it, error messages would be corectly displayed. Just add following line in your `it()` block: `expect(true).toBe(true)`

Comment: @silvanBregy: I would really like to work with you on the live example to crack this issue. But, since this is a multi dollar commercial project, I'm not allowed to set/share any information regarding the same outside the domain:( I did try with expect(true).toBe(true) inside it() block and there weren't any error on the console this time. So, it narrows down the issue to be on the logger statement 'Logging.info("foo");' Are we calling it the correct way ?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer (update2). Please try the code on your machine.If it works, we have another problem. If not, it may be something permissions related?

Comment: @SilvanBregy: It did work in my machine pal. I could see the update2 example had written the expected log messages. what could be the issue in our code and its not working there ? :(

Comment: @SilvanBregy: Bingo! I compared the working example and removed the "format: 'simple'" from LoggingMech.js and could witness the msgs to be written in our log as well now. So happy that we are progressing ahead :) The culprit is the 'format'. How do we define this now and how to capture the logs for each of the It() block pal ?

Comment: Please read through the `winston` npm site.  It tells you how to set up formats. If you aren't able just ping me back. I actually did not work with winston yet. 
=> https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#formats

Comment: I was able to add the format now and altered the way the logger should look pal "2018-09-19 18:42:12 info: Hello distributed log files!". But, don't know how to call in an It() block and capture all the logs that I'm currently capturing in the console and all the error msgs if there are any while the test runs and the browser errors etc.